# How to Correct UI without introducing a new blank div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Following is the code in which I am managing divs using `Flexbox`. To match the UI I placed a dummy blank div so that second row items match correctly with the above one.

- Box11 takes same width as Box 01
- Box12 takes same width as Box 02
- But Box 13 to take width = Box 03 + Box 04
- Items inside Box13 should be right aligned.

Let me know if I can achieve this without introducing a dummy div or is there any cleaner or better approach to this ?

**Code -**

```css
.container { padding: 20px 0;}

.wrong { border: 5px solid red;}
.correct { border: 5px solid green;}

.row { display: flex; padding: 0 1%; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.box { flex: 1; margin: 0 1%; border: 1px solid teal;}

.button-box { display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse;}
```

```html
<p>WRONG UI</p>
<div class="container wrong">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box first">This is a test Box 01</div>
    <div class="box second">This is a test Box 02</div>
    <div class="box third">This is a test Box 03</div>
    <div class="box forth">This is a test Box 04</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box first">This is a test Box 11</div>
    <div class="box second">This is a test Box 12</div>
    <div class="box third button-box">
      Box 13
      <button>Button 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>CORRECT UI - bcoz of additional div</p>

<div class="container correct">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box first">This is a test Box 01</div>
    <div class="box second">This is a test Box 02</div>
    <div class="box third">This is a test Box 03</div>
    <div class="box forth">This is a test Box 04</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box first">This is a test Box 11</div>
    <div class="box second">This is a test Box 12</div>
    <div class="box second"></div>
    <div class="box third button-box">
      Box 13
      <button>Button 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the picture about what are you getting now and what you want to do, Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `flex: 2;` to box 13. this will make it as big as box 3 and 4

Comment: With the `border` and the `margin` it won't align.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unnecessary `div` and change following css property

```
.button-box { display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse;flex: 2}
```

```css
.container { padding: 20px 0;}

.correct { border: 5px solid green;}

.row { display: flex; padding: 0 1%; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.box { flex: 1; margin: 0 1%; border: 1px solid teal;}

.button-box { display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse;flex: 2}
```

```html
<div class="container correct">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box first">This is a test Box 01</div>
    <div class="box second">This is a test Box 02</div>
    <div class="box third">This is a test Box 03</div>
    <div class="box forth">This is a test Box 04</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box first">This is a test Box 11</div>
    <div class="box second">This is a test Box 12</div>
    <div class="box third button-box">
      Box 13
      <button>Button 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```